# permanently save new entered data in list view

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

Hi i make a sales puchase app like olx. In which user post free add. Problem is when use post add it appeared in listview but when user again login with their device the add will disappear.....

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_adds_layout, parent, false);
    TextView title = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    TextView detailedMessage = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.detailed_message);
    TextView ownerName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.owner);
    TextView ownerEmail = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.owner_email);
    TextView price = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.price);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView10);
    Button btn33 = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.buybutton);
    btn33.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buy_corner);
    btn33.setOnClickListener(this);

    Advertisement dataObj = values[position];
    title.setText(dataObj.getTitle());
    detailedMessage.setText(dataObj.getDetailedMessage());
    ownerName.setText(dataObj.getOwnerName());
    ownerEmail.setText(dataObj.getOwnerEmail());
    price.setText(String.valueOf(dataObj.getPrice()));
    btn33.setTag(price.getText());
    if(dataObj.getImageId().contains(">>>")){
        String picturePath = dataObj.getImageId().replace(">>>", ""); 
        image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
    }else {
        setDrawable(image, dataObj.getImageId());
    }

    return rowView;

}

private void setDrawable(ImageView image, String drawableName) {
    AssetManager manager = image.getContext().getAssets();

    // Read a Bitmap from Assets
    InputStream open = null;
    try {
        open = manager.open(drawableName+".jpg");
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(open);
        // Assign the bitmap to an ImageView in this layout
        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (open != null) {
            try {
                open.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

And here is my Xml

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/parentLinear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="410dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="66dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="Ad Title!"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            android:typeface="serif" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter Title Here" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="66dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextDescription"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter Description Here" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Ad\nDescription!"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            android:typeface="serif" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="62dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextOwnerName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter Name Here" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editTextOwnerName"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Owner\nName!"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            android:typeface="serif" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextOwnerEmail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter Email id Here" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="Owner\nEmail"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            android:typeface="serif" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="62dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="Ad Price!"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            android:typeface="serif" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextPrice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter Price Here" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonAddImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="Add Image"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            android:typeface="serif" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/creatae"
            android:layout_width="100sp"
            android:layout_height="100sp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSaveAdd"
        android:layout_width="68dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Save"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

By click on save add

```
case R.id.buttonSaveAdd:
        EditText editTextTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTitle);
        EditText editTextDes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextDescription);
        EditText editTextOwner = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextOwnerName);
        EditText editTextOwnerEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextOwnerEmail);
        EditText editTextPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPrice);

        //populating data object from the values received 
        //from view
        String title = editTextTitle.getText().toString(); 
        String description = editTextDes.getText().toString();
        String ownerName = editTextOwner.getText().toString();
        String ownerEmail = editTextOwnerEmail.getText().toString();
        String pricce = editTextPrice.getText().toString();
        Advertisement  object = new Advertisement(title, description,
                ownerName, ownerEmail, currentImageName, Integer.parseInt(pricce), 100);
        Button_mak.ads.add(object);

        this.finish();
        break;
```

Comment: its good if you save these in a local database.

Comment: ok but how??? plz suggest me some link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save them in a local database using SQLite and then reload them back into the listview when the user opens that activity again. I made a blog post recently on using SQLite within Android. It can be found [here](http://programthat.wordpress.com/2014/07/19/beginning-sqlite-in-android/)

Comment: hi i want to listview data with image in database.